# vba example on how add a item to a Sharepoint list programmatically

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to update and add items/rows to a SharePoint list using VBA. Each Item in my list has 5 fields.  I have tried the code in the following link, but could not get it to to work: [Add and Update Single Item in Sharepoint List via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450717/add-and-update-single-item-in-sharepoint-list-via-vba).

I feel that I just need good vba examples of how to update and add items.  Any insight and examples are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which part of the code did not work, and what sort of error message did it give?

Comment: The code runs and gives objXMLHTTP.Status of 400 but no response text.   I'm passing the list name, Sharepoint URL, a value, and field name to Add_Item. Example ValueVar = "test_title" and FieldNameVar = "Title".  However, I'm not sure I'm passing the FieldNameVar and ValueVar correctly, since i'm trying to add an entire new entry which includes multiple cols/fields, but only pass information for one field.

Comment: That sounds like `SharepointUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"` doesn't exist.